# Get the path used on terminal the call script

Tags: python

How do I get the path used on terminal that called my Python script.
Example: with the terminal in $HOME, calling `python -m my_script` or even `my_script` I want to now that the script was called from `$HOME` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing the basic usage of [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

> `os.getcwd()`
>    Return a string representing the current working directory.